Interactive charts with flask python and no javascript
Is it possible to create interactive charts (if yes - how?) in a web app using just html and flask/ python, without writing own javascript?
I don't want Django as it seems an overkill for a medim app I am building.
Thank you
Stackoverflow says that my question was already answered here:
This question already has answers here:
How to execute python code on client side using flask? (2 answers)
Can Python be used for client side web development? [closed] (8 answers)
I dont think this is true. I dont't belive there is information in the "dupplicate" questions relevant to what I asked.
udemy, youtube, google, stackoverflow

you can't do interactive plot without JavaScript- even if you use special Python version which can run in browser then it also runs JavaScript code. But when you use plotly in flask then mostly you don't have to write any JavaScript code. You may need it only when you want to add extra functions. The same can be with Streamlit (which is based on flask) but as for me some functions are too much hidden and it is hard to add own functions in JavaScript.

there is also Bokeh, Streamsync. but they don't use flask. You can also try to create it in Jupyter and later convert to web page using ie. Solara, JupyterLite, Voici

Thank you, furas, that is helpful. Currently all my stuff is in plotly dash. It provides interactivity to plotly charts. From your answer I understand that if I want interactivity (click on chart, click event data passed to python backend,  python tells other chart / map what to display) I cannot do this without JS.

I may trying wrapping my dash app in a "master" flask app which, in turn, should allow me to add authentication and some other pages, not built in plotly dash, unless I am mistaken?
https://hackersandslackers.com/plotly-dash-with-flask/
